# Preparing data for mean-variance portfolio analysis

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to perform a mean-variance portfolio optimization using MATLAB on a universe of 13 assets, and am unsure that my methodology for preparing asset data for analysis is sound. Here is what I currently do for each asset:

1. Download monthly price and dividend data from Yahoo! Finance.
2. Convert price and dividend data to my home currency (NZD).
3. Use the function `totalreturnprice` to convert monthly price and dividend data into a total return price time series.

Total return price time series data for all 13 assets is then collated into a single NUMOBS * 13 matrix called `all_asset_return_prices`, and the mean and covariance of the universe of assets is then estimated using the command:

```
p = p.estimateAssetMoments(all_asset_return_prices, 'MissingData', false);
```

My concern is this. MATLAB's documentation for `estimateAssetMoments` states that it expects total return data, and not total return *price* data as I have generated. However, if I convert my total return price data to total return data by either:

1. Using the function `periodicreturns`
2. Passing `estimateAssetMoments` the 'DataFormat' / 'prices' name-value pair

The resulting plots of risk vs return for the assets seem outlandish, ie mean returns or variances that do not seem realistic. Can anyone comment on failings in the procedure outlined above, or point me at a reference that deals specifically with preparing data for analysis? The MATLAB Financial Toolbox documentation is tremendous when it comes to describing how to analyse portfolio data, but is not so great at explaining how to prepare the data in the first place.

Please note that I do not have access to the datafeed toolbox, and so need to prepare the data manually.

Comment: `estimateAssetMoments` has an option input argument that allows you to specify if the **AssetReturns** input is return or price series data.  Have you tried using it?

Comment: Indeed I have - see point two above.

Comment: @RBE How did you create `p` initially?